# C# Winforms UDPClient Exception: "Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted."

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, networking

I'm working on a GUI in C#/Winforms that communicates with another system via UDP. I'm using the DotNet 'UdpClient' class for this. I'm using one socket for each transmitting, and one for receiving:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(receiveport_num);
client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,     SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,     SocketOptionName.ExclusiveAddressUse, false);
client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, client);

UdpClient server = new UdpClient(ConnectionSettings.soport);
server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ExclusiveAddressUse, false);
```

Then receiving from the 'server' socket with server.Send.

Once I am done with the sockets, or the application is closed, they are disposed of thusly:

```
client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Client.Close();
client.Close();
client = null;

server.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
server.Client.Close();
server.Close();
server = null;
```

For some reason, if I try to re-create these sockets, either by creating the sockets again or restarting the application, I get an exception:

```
System: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network) is normally permitted.
```

I understand the this is because even though I am closing the sockets, the underlying Windows sockets are lingering around because Windows is keeping them alive...

I want to use the same port numbers and recreate the sockets each time. How can I do this? If this is not possible (which sounds like a bit of a networking issue in Windows if you ask me...), then is there a way that I can re-acquire the sockets for my use?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what's wrong. But rest assured, you shouldn't need to call `SetSocketOption()` to get things working. Note also that you should not call `Shutdown()` on a UDP socket. That's for connection-oriented sockets. I haven't tested myself, but it's possible it's the `Shutdown()` that's causing the linger state and leading to the error message.

Comment: _"I'm using one socket for each transmitting, and one for receiving:"_ -- this is fine for testing purposes, i.e. to put two endpoints in the same program. But otherwise, don't. One socket can both receive and send. And if you want two endpoints in the same program, or even on the same computer, those endpoints need to use different port #'s. Don't try to make more than one socket on the same computer with the same port #.

Comment: I'll try removing the `Shutdown()`, however looking at the MDSN documentation that shouldn't cause problems... I should be more specific about the sockets: These are two different sockets, using two different ports. One is receiving from port X, the other is sending on port Y. The whole `SetSocketOption` thing wasn't there before, it's just my attempt at getting the socket to free itself properly. I've used the exact same architecture in other OS's without an issue, so this seems to be more of an issue with the way Windows handles these things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My application was spawning processes using `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo pi)`. When using this function, all handles belonging to the main application process (including sockets) are inherited by the child.

When the parent process died, the child was still active, keeping the socket open. This can be solved in one of two ways:

a) Using P/Invoke, replace the `Process.Start` with [`createprocess()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createprocess), setting `bInheritHandles` to false. As far as I can tell, the dotNet `Process.Start` function has nothing equivalent, which in my opinion is an oversight.

b) Using P/Invoke, after creating each socket you don't want the child process to inherit, call [`SetHandleInformation()`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetHandleInformation.html) with `INHERIT` as the `dwMask` parameter, and `NONE` as the `dwFlags` parameter.